# Difference between ffmpeg and avconv for rawvideo image2pipe

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, avconv

I'm not sure why, but `avconv` does not seem to be piping raw video like I would expect.

I'm trying pipe a video from `ffmpeg` into `python` (eventually I want to read from `x11grab`, not a video file). It works just fine on my Macbook using `ffmpeg`, but when I use `avconv` on Debian Jessie, the stream cuts off early!

Here's my basic python, which is following [this guide](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/):

```
input_resolution_shape = (1280,800,3)
input_bytes = reduce(mul, input_resolution_shape, 1)
print input_bytes

# Prints 3072000

import subprocess as sp
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,   # This is either "avconv" or "ffmpeg".
            '-i', 'test_video.mp4',
            '-f', 'image2pipe',
            '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
            '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

import numpy
for _ in range(100):  # read 100 frames
    # read 1280*800*3 bytes (= 1 frame)
    raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(input_bytes)
    # transform the byte read into a numpy array
    image = numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
    if image.size != 0:
        print image.size

        # Prints 1015808
```

On the mac, the `image.size` printed is the same as the `input_bytes`, 3072000. But on debian, it's 1015808. Any ideas why that could be happening?

Interestingly, 3072000/1015808 is just about 3:

```
In [1]:    3072000./1015808.
Out[1]:    3.024193548387097
```

Comment: `acvonv` is not equivalent to `ffmpeg`. Why don't you just use `ffmpeg`? You can simply [download a static `ffmpeg` binary](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and point your script to it.

Comment: Because I'm on Debian and I can't figure out how to correctly install ffmpeg on it. :(

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because I am running from inside a Docker instance, which is built off of Debian. `ffmpeg` isn't packaged by default in the version of Debian I'm running.

I managed to fix this problem by just downloading an `ffmpeg` binary, per @LordNeckbeard's comment above. I've added these lines to my `Dockerfile` which solve the problem for me:

```
# Install FFMPEG
RUN wget http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
RUN tar xvfJ ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
USER root
RUN ln ffmpeg-3.1.2-64bit-static/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

Thanks.